# Javascript event not triggered if the change origin is not from the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to understand why the change event in the following example is not triggered (I'll show exactly where).

I have a checkbox, lets call it 'mainCheckbox', when checked - I want to check some other related checkboxes (so far working).

In addition when I uncheck one of the related checkboxes (child checkboxes) - I want to uncheck the mainCheckbox, this also works - but here is something I am failing to understand:

I am changing the checked property of the mainCheckbox (in the `onchange` handler of the 'childCheckbox'),

How come the `onchange` handler of mainCheckbox is not invoked? 
Or how come the `onchange` event of the main checkbox is not triggered?

here is the code:

```
//binding to the 'mainCheckbox' change event:
$("[data-role='group']").bind("change", function(event){
    //checking / unchecking all related checkboxes respectivly
    $("li input[data-group='" + event.target.id + "'").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
})

//binding to the change event of every 'child checkbox'
$("li input[data-group]").bind("change", function(){
    if (event.target.checked){
        //if the child checkbox is now checked - I am checking if now all child checkboxes are checked,
        //if so - I need to check the main checkbox.
        if ($("[data-group=" + event.target.dataset.group + "]:checked").length == $("[data-group=" + event.target.dataset.group + "]").length){
            $("#" + event.target.dataset.group).prop("checked", true);
        }
        //TODO: add this device to the selectedDevices array.
    }
    else {
        //the checkbox is now unchecked - so I am unchecking the main checkbox -
        //but here is my failing to understand part: I am unchecking the main checkbox - 
        //why the change event is not triggered? I thought that now all child checkboxes will be unchecked as well
        //(I am happy they are not :) just failing to understand why)...
        $("#" + event.target.dataset.group).prop("checked", false);
        //TODO: remove this device from the selectedDevices array.
        
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Are you changing the "clicked" property of the main checkbox in its change handler? Is this a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the events are only fired in response to *user* actions, not actions in code. Setting the `checked` property on a checkbox does not fire its `change` event; the *user* changing the checkbox's checked state does.

This is also true for when you use code to set the `value` of an `input`, the `selectedIndex` (or `value`) of a `select`, etc.

It's also true in relation to the `submit` events on `form` elements: Calling an `HTMLFormElement`'s `submit` function will submit the form without triggering its `submit` event. **But**, if you use jQuery to submit the form (e.g., if you call `submit` on a jQuery object wrapped around an `HTMLFormElement`), it **does** trigger its `submit` event handlers. This is an unfortunate by-product of jQuery's API design.

If you want to trigger an event, you can do that with jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) function. So if it's appropriate, after setting `checked`, you could `.trigger("change")`. In general I advocate **not** generating synthetic predefined events like that (instead, just call whatever function you need to call, or use a synthetic custom event), but there are valid use cases.

Comment: In addition, you should take a look at jQuery.trigger http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ This is how you can execute certain event handlers porgrammatically.

Answer (score 1):

Onchange event is fired when the element loses focus. Since you are changing the value programmatically, the element you are changing never loses focus. You may wish to check the `oninput` event.

Comment: `input` won't fire if you change the checkbox via code either. The fundamental here has nothing to do with focus. The fundamental is whether it was a *user action* or program code.

Comment: You are most probably right. I didn't check that to be honest.